# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выполнение функции останавливалось?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_cancel = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отменить', callback_data='cancel')
    keyboard.add(key_cancel)
    if call.data == "report":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         '<i>Опишите проблему, Ваше сообщение будет доставлено администрации и принято на рассмотрение!\n</i>',
                         parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboard)
        if call.data == 'cancel':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             '<b><i>Отменено!</i></b>',
                             parse_mode='HTML')
        else:
            bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, report_send)
    elif call.data == "support":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         '<i>Опишите Вашу идею, сообщение будет доставлено администрации и принято на рассмотрение!\n</i>',
                         parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboard)
        if call.data == 'cancel':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             '<b><i>Отменено!</i></b>',
                             parse_mode='HTML')
        else:
            bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, support_send)
```

Мне нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку `cancel` выполнение функций (`support_send() или report_send()`) останавливалось, либо же чтоб оно вообще не начиналось, пока пользователь не напишет сообщение.
Использование асинхронных библиотек возможно, но не желательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил это добавлением глобальной переменной `callback_cancel`, которая изначально равна False.
Обработку нажатия на кнопку `Отменить` я вынес из `if`:

```
elif call.data == 'cancel':
        global callback_cancel
        callback_cancel = True
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         '<b><i>Отменено!</i></b>',
                         parse_mode='HTML')
```

При нажатии на кнопку `callback_cancel` становится True, и, когда `next_step_handler` получает сообщение, если `callback_cancel == True` он придает переменной обратно значение False и прекращает выполнение функции.

```
def report_send(message):
    if callback_cancel:
        callback_cancel = False
        return
```